# Why does this generate an infinite loop (C, While Loop)

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, infinite

I am doing a program for my class, and I need to set all the values of the array 'decade' into -1 before I begin.  I tried this (And the version in a for loop) and it just puts me in an infinite loop!  Can someone explain why this is happening, and how I can fix it?

Code:

```
int decade[9][9], i = 0, k = 0;
while (i<10) {
    while (k<10) {
        printf("i is %d, k is %d\n",i,k);
        decade[i][k] = -1;
        k++;
    }
    k=0;
    i++;
}
```

Thanks in advanced!

It prints out this:
[image: What it prints out]

**For anyone who needs the answer in the future, declare decade as 'decade[10][10]' instead of 'decade[9][9]', or however yours is defined.**

Comment: initial value for ``i`` and ``k``?

Comment: What does it print out?

Comment: Sorry, didn't include the part where i and k are both declared as '0', putting it in...

Comment: How is `decade` declared? How do you initialize it?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Refresh page, just stuck that in there

Comment: Compiling & running that code on my machine does not result in an infinite loop.  We'll have to see the actual code.

Comment: 0 -> 9  is 10 items  so [9][9] isn't enough room

Comment: I added a picture as to what it prints out.

Comment: @Beaurocks16: But an array declared with `[9]` will only have 9 elements, with indices from 0 through 8.

Comment: @jwodder Just realized that, removed that part of the comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you declare an array of size `9` it has the indexes from `0` to `8`. You go to `9` which will overwrite the memory. This is *undefined behavior* and can cause any number of subtle but faulty behavior.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how "decade" is defined - but if it is defined incorrectly, and/or the wrong size you *could* get a buffer overrun which *could* result in the wrong memory getting set to "-1" - i.e. the "i" or "k" variables could be getting overwritten.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a buffer overflow and not a memory leak.

Comment: A buffer overflow is a *type* of memory leak - but it isn't necessarily an "overflow". It could be wrong in one dimension, it could have the wrong number of dimensions, it could be of the wrong type, etc.

Comment: @Brad No, a memory leak is something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

```
int decade[9][9], i = 0, k = 0;
while (i<10) {
    while (k<10) {
        printf("i is %d, k is %d\n",i,k);
        decade[i][k] = -1;
        k++;
    }
    k=0;
    i++;
}
```

is incorrect, because you are iterationg from 0 to 9 (10 elements)

this code is correct:

```
int decade[9][9], i = 0, k = 0;
while (i<9) {
   k = 0;

   while (k<9) {
      printf("i is %d, k is %d\n",i,k);
      decade[i][k] = -1;
      k++;
   }

i++;
}
```

note that you set k to zero *before* looping again.

There exists also other possibilities to loop for example the `for` loop, you use while loops actually not for counting.

Answer (score 1):

You loops must be from 0 to 8 (decade array is length 9):

```
while (i<9) {
    while (k<9) {
       /* ... */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The dimension in "9x9" - you are initialzing 10x10. Set it to decade[10][10], use (x<8) or do (x<=9)

Answer (score 0):

```
Index out of bound exception for your code. Try this one instead.

   int dimSize = 10;
    int decade[dimSize][dimSize], i = 0, k = 0;
    while (i<dimSize) {
        while (k<dimSize) {
            printf("i is %d, k is %d\n",i,k);
            decade[i][k] = -1;
            k++;
        }
        k=0;
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Not the quickest, but both defines the problem and gives an example.

Comment: A programmer can easily understand what CODE I typed :)